# Where is the best place to find diamond or gold in survival mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the most efficient Minecraft mining strategy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/whats-the-most-efficient-minecraft-mining-strategy)
>   [What is the best layer to mine for gold in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20635/what-is-the-best-layer-to-mine-for-gold-in-minecraft)

I can never find gold or diamond and me and my friends are dying to know where you find it. And also, does the diamond pickaxe last forever?

Comment: No, the diamond pickaxe lasts for 1562 uses, but it is possible for it to last up to 4 times as long as that with the Unbreaking III enchantment.

Comment: The best level to mine for diamonds at is level 11 (Y-coordinate 11)

Comment: layer 11 underground