# What are the major levels for Mining?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When mining for resources, there are "levels" that each resource appear. For example, Diamonds appear at levels 11-16 (roughly).

Can someone list all of the ranges for each major resource? (Coal, Iron, Gold, Redstone, Diamond, Emerald, etc)

And for some of the more common resources, like Coal or Iron, is there a range where they are more commonly found? I.e. If Diamond only appears at level 11-16, is it likely they occur more often at level 13 for example?

Comment: Do you mean `y`?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 yes

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/20666/101452 This will probably help. There are some nice links in the answers and comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ore) page to find more about the locations of ores.

Here are the `y` coordinates that the ores are most commonly found in.

- Coal: 5-52
- Iron: 5-54
- Lapis Lazuli: 14-16
- Gold: 5-29
- Diamond: 5-12
- Redstone: 5-12
- Emerald: 5-29 (*Note*: only in Extreme Hills Biome)
- Nether Quartz: 10-114
- Ancient Debris: 6-21
- Nether Gold: 15

Answer (score -1):

Lapis is best found between 17-19 and diamond 12. You can check the y coordinate by looking on your map. (this was from more posts from this website)

Comment: _"(this was from more posts from this website)"_ - Could you [edit] in the source (links to the other posts) to show the evidence?